# how to use istream_iterators to split an equation?

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

I'm trying to split a string like `( 1 + 2 )` into a vector and when using an `istream_iterators<string>` it doesn't split the parentheses so I get vector outputs like

`(1 , + , 2)` when I want `( , 1, + , 2 ,)`

Is it possible to use `istream_iterator`s to achieve this?

```
string eq = "(1 + 2)";

istringstream ss(eq);
istream_iterator<string> begin(ss);
istream_iterator<string> end;
vector<string> vec(begin, end);
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: sry first time posting i just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it using `istream_iterator`.  Instead, simply do it by hand:

```
vector<string> vec;
vec.reserve(eq.size() / 4); // rough guess
bool in_number = false;
for (char ch : eq) {
    if (isspace(ch)) {
        in_number = false;
    } else if (isdigit(ch)) {
        if (in_number) {
            vec.back().push_back(ch);
        } else {
            vec.emplace_back(1, ch);
            in_number = true;
        }
    } else {
        vec.emplace_back(1, ch);
        in_number = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I though that since it is a vector<string> you cant  'push_back' a 'char' onto a 'vector<string> '

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a custom type `Token` and using it with 
`istream_iterator`. Bonus feature: this code will parse multiple digits, multiple operators, and nested expressions. So enjoy. :)

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

class Token {
private:
  string val;
public:
  Token() : val("") {}
  Token(string& v) : val(v) {}
  friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, Token& tok);
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Token& tok);
};

istream& operator>>(istream &in, Token& tok) {
  char c;
  string v;
  if (in >> c) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
      v.push_back(c);
      while (in >> c && isdigit(c)) {
    v.push_back(c);
      }
      in.putback(c);
    } else if (c == ' ') {
      while (in >> c && c == ' ') ;
      in.putback(c);
    } else {
      v.push_back(c);
    }
  }
  tok = v;
  return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Token& tok) {
  out << tok.val;
  return out;
}

int main() {
  string eq = "(1 + 2)";
  //eq = "(100 + 200)"; // multiple digits
  //eq = "(100 + 200 * 300)"; // extra operator
  //eq = "(100 + (200 * 300))"; // nested parens

  istringstream ss(eq);
  istream_iterator<Token> begin(ss);
  istream_iterator<Token> end;
  vector<Token> vec(begin, end);
  for (auto& x : vec) {
    cout << "[" <<  x << "] ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```